# moving to a node values in linq to xml C#?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying get the email value under author node in C#. But nothing is coming. My Code is=

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse("myxml");
var foos = from xelem in xDoc.Descendants("author")
               select xelem.Element("email").Value;
```

XML which i am using is -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:batch="http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch" 

xmlns:gContact="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" 

xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/">
 <id>yogeshcp13@gmail.com</id>
 <updated>2015-02-09T04:03:31.220Z</updated>
 <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"/>
 <title type="text">Yogesh Adhikari's Contacts</title>
 <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://www.google.com/"/>
 <link rel="next" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/yogeshcs2003%40gmail.com/full?max-

results=1&amp;start-index=2"/>
 <author>
  <name>Yogesh Adhikari</name>
  <email>yogeshcp13@gmail.com</email>
 </author>
 <generator version="1.0" uri="http://www.google.com/m8/feeds">Contacts</generator>
 <openSearch:totalResults>3099</openSearch:totalResults>
 <openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
 <openSearch:itemsPerPage>1</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
</feed>
```

Can someone point out what is wrong?
Thanks

Comment: you should have also posted XML also along with the question you are trying to parse.

Comment: The element names are in the `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom` namespace.

Comment: i am trying to use linq to get to the node 'author' but failing?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the namespace along with the name when getting the descendants.

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse("myxml");
string ns = xDoc.Root.Name.Namespace;

var foos = from xelem in xDoc.Descendants(ns + "author")
           select xelem.Element(ns + "email").Value;
```

Alternatively, you can find your nodes by getting an enumeration over *all* descendants, then filtering by `LocalName`. If `email` is a node only within `author`s in your schema, you can also avoid the unnecessary step of drilling down from `author` nodes, and just find your `email` nodes directly:

```
var foos = xdoc.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "email");
```

Comment: what is 'xDocument' in 2nd line?

Comment: @yogihosting Sorry, that should be `xDoc`.

Comment: thanks the first code did not worked, but your last line code of  lambda expression works perfectly. Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("myxml.xml");
var foos = xDoc.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "email");
Console.WriteLine(foos.FirstOrDefault().Value);
```

Use Load method if you are refering to xml file else parse should be fine. Also make sure xml is along with your binaries' folder if not using specific path.